# why is my compiler complaining when i try to clear the cin buffer

Tags: c++, buffer, cin

i am writing a program where i am trying to implement the following code:

```
int main(){

string inputcmd;


while (getline(cin, inputcmd)){
    cout << "TYPE A COMMAND" << endl;   
    cin >> inputcmd;

    cin.ignore (std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); 

    if (inputcmd == "make"){
        cout << "MAKING NEW PROJECT" << endl;
        get_project(cin);
    }

    else if (inputcmd == "retrieve"){
        cout << "RETRIEVING YOUR PROJECT" << endl;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

i am trying to use the cin.ignore property to clear the buffer of the newline character currently residing in the buffer at that given time, however when i try and compile it is giving me a bunch of gibberish compiler error? why is this how can i fix this?

Comment: When you post a question about build errors, always include the complete and unedited error log. No matter if it seems to be gibberish to you, or if it's a lot, it helps us to understand what's happening.

Comment: post the errors also..

Comment: By the way, you *do* include `<limits>`, which is needed for [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits)? (Another tip about posting code, please make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) containing the problem, and post that complete.)

Comment: Apart from the error message itself, you are missing the includes and using directives you seem to have used. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: i included limits and now it compiles. however now it for some reason just gets stuck in the first main while loop, the program runs and asks to TYPE A COMMAND but thats all it asks for, sometimes you have to press newline a couple of times before it ask for it again. how can i remedy this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you included

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

Then I'm not getting any error.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a strange combination of `getline` and `cin`... If you're using `getline`, you don't have to call `cin.ignore` at all. Don't mix both like you did or you will get confusing results.

This example propably runs like you want:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  string inputcmd;
  bool running = true;
  while (running){
    cout << "TYPE A COMMAND" << endl;
    getline(cin, inputcmd);
    if (inputcmd.substr(0, inputcmd.find(" ")) == "make"){
      if(inputcmd.find(" ")!=string::npos){
        inputcmd = inputcmd.substr(inputcmd.find(" ")+1);
        cout << "MAKING NEW PROJECT: " << inputcmd << endl;
        //get_project(cin);
      }else{
        cout << "make: not enough arguments" << endl;
      }
    }else if (inputcmd == "retrieve"){
      cout << "RETRIEVING YOUR PROJECT" << endl;
    }else if(inputcmd == ""){
      running = false;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to put a condition around that `getline` call. What if the user presses the EOF key-combination or there is some error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to press an extra newline because you read the input *twice*. First with `getline` and a second time with `cin >> ...`.

If you can have arguments to the commands, I recommend you remove the `cin >> ...` part, together with the `cin.ignore()` call, and use only `getline` and [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream):

```
std::cout << "Enter command: ";
while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    // Get the command
    std::string command;
    iss >> command;

    if (command == "make")
    {
        ...
    }
    ...

    std::cout << "Enter command: ";
}
```

This way, you can easily get the space-separated arguments to the command as well.

And yes, you have code to print the prompt twice, but that is a smaller and negligible problem in my opinion.

---

Or if you want to be even more general, use e.g. a `std::vector` to store the command and arguments, and do something like

```
std::cout << "Enter command: ";
while (std::getline(cin, line))
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    std::vector<std::string> args;

    // Get the command and all arguments, and put them into the `args` vector
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
              std::back_inserter(args));

    if (args[0] == "make")
    {
        ...
    }
    ...

    std::cout << "Enter command: ";
}
```

See e.g. these references:

- [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)
- [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator)
- [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter)